# Sum the columns for duplicate records

Tags: excel, calculation

I would like to sum the values in L column for the ID's highlighted in yellow. I am not a excel expert ,i hope can get some help here. Thanks.

example: ID T1701273578753377 in H column made multiple purchses thus it it has multiple records,And you can see the amount in column L. I would like to sum the values in L for ID T1701273578753377 and all other IDs.

[image]

Comment: Try using `SUMIFS`.

Answer (score 1):

```
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(H1:H9),SUMIF(H1:H9,UNIQUE(H1:H9),L1:L9))
```

[image]

Or a little bit shorter:

```
=LET(a,UNIQUE(H1:H9),HSTACK(a,SUMIF(H1:H9,a,L1:L9)))
```